# Calculate the average difference between "v2" - "v1" on each row. How to weigh it with the treatment time?

Tags: sql, average, difference

I have this table

| time1 | time2 | v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 00:30 | 60.4369 | 120.438 |
| 00:24 | 00:50 | 25.5948 | 53.7444 |

And I have about 50 rows

I tried to build smth like
AVG (SUM v2 - SUM v1) but it's not quite correct
Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `AVG(v2-v1)`?  And what do you mean by "weigh it with the treatment time"?

Comment: What would be the expected result in the example with two rows only?

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.